# How to increase performance of shortest path using Gremlin?

Tags: graph, cassandra, shortest-path, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm using JanusGraph with Gremlin and [this](http://networkrepository.com/road-minnesota.php) dataset cotaining 2.6k nodes and 6.6k edges (3.3k edges on both sides). I've run the query for 10 minutes without find the shortest path.

Using Gephi the shortest path is almost instantaneous.

Here's my query:

```
g.V(687).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId(1343)).path().limit(1)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `simplePath()` your query still processes a lot more paths than necessary. For example, if `688` is a direct neighbor of `687`, but also a neighbor of `1000`, which is 10 hops away on another path, why would you want to follow the path from `1000` to `688`, if you've already seen this crossroad much earlier?

So, you should filter out any crossroad that you've seen before (the first occurrence is always the closest):

```
g.V(687).store('x').
  repeat(out().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).
   until(hasId(1343)).limit(1).path()
```

Also note, that I swapped `limit(1)` and `path`; that's because it's a waste of resources (CPU and memory) to gather all paths first and then just take the first one.

**UPDATE:**

If others want to give it a try, here's the code to load the dataset into TinkerGraph:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
"http://nrvis.com/download/data/road/road-minnesota.zip".toURL().withInputStream {
  new java.util.zip.ZipInputStream(it).with {
    while (entry = it.getNextEntry()) {
      if ("road-minnesota.mtx" == entry.getName()) {
        it.eachLine {
          if (it ==~ /[0-9]+ [0-9]+/) {
            def (a, b) = it.split()*.toInteger()
            g.V(a).fold().
              coalesce(unfold(), addV().property(id, a)).
              addE("road").
                to(V(b).fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV().property(id, b))).inV().
              addE("road").to(V(a)).iterate()
          }
        }
        break
      }
      it.closeEntry()
    }
  }
}
```

And the query and a little benchmark:

```
gremlin> g.V(687).store('x').
......1>   repeat(out().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).
......2>    until(hasId(1343)).limit(1).
......3>   path().by(id)
==>[687,689,686,677,676,675,673,626,610,606,607,608,735,732,733,730,729,734,737,738,739,742,786,816,840,829,815,825,865,895,872,874,968,983,1009,1044,1140,1142,1148,1219,1255,1329,1337,1339,1348,1343]

gremlin> clock (100) {
......1>   g.V(687).store('x').
......2>     repeat(out().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).
......3>      until(hasId(1343)).limit(1).
......4>     path().iterate()
......5> }
==>12.5362714
```

12.5 ms on TinkerGraph looks pretty good to me. Expect it to run a little bit longer on JG, but surely not more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Would you mind explaining in greater detail how `g.V(687).store('x').
  repeat(out().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).
   until(hasId(1343)).limit(1).path()` works? What would happen if out nodes out of g.V(687) were executed in an order that a longer path went first, wouldn't that prevent a shorter path from ever being tried? How does `repeat(out()..` guarantee that the shortest path is first?

Comment: It's BFS, hence shortest paths will always come first.