# without step translate to gremlin python

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm so helped by this.
[How to increase performance of shortest path using Gremlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239642/how-to-increase-performance-of-shortest-path-using-gremlin)

I want to know how to translate this gremlin query to gremlin-python

```
g.V(687).store('x').repeat(out().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).until(hasId(1343)).limit(1).path()
```

like ...

```
g.V(687).store('x').repeat(__.out().where(without('x')).aggregate('x')).until(__.hasId(1343)).limit(1).path()
```

Comment: is it ok? 
`from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P
g.V(687).store('x').repeat(__.out().where(P.neq('x')).aggregate('x')).until(__.hasId(1343)).limit(1).path()`

Comment: timeout occurred. `where(P.neq('x')).aggregate('x')` might not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use `P.without` in your Python code.